Regex to DFA question, don't understand why it is this way
I've been dealing with problem 10 on Leetcode (Regular expression matching), where you are supposed to write a program that matches strings to a given regex.I wrote a solution in C that had passed 308 of 356 test cases and stuck on this particular problem. solution in github
ab*a*c*a that takes "aaa" string.
In the test case output it happens to be true, but not in my solution. I tried to look at DFA (deterministic finite automata) of this regex

And my question is why is state 4 in the DFA an accepting state? Because if we start by a, then pass b* and match the two as that are left in the input string we are left with the empty string and extra a in regex.

When the regex ab*a*c*a matches aa, the second a in the input string matches the final a in the regex.  b*, a*, and c* are all matched by empty strings between the two as.

Thanks a lot for your answer! But it is still unclear to me how an algorithm can tell if there is a final a or not to be able to match a* to empty string?

The easiest way is to try both possibilities.  That's what the java regex engine does.  The hard way is to build a DFA, via Thompson's construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) to create a NFA and powerset construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerset_construction) to make it a DFA.
